# OpenUI/Swagger java to API

Tags: java, rest, swagger-ui, openapi

Creating rest api project using spring boot + OpenUI/Swagger for api description.

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.6'
```

Rest api is complex. Each rest endpoint in result sending callback. Which can be described in OpenApi UI(and in generated yaml).
This is how im describing callbacks in java code:

```
@Callbacks({

    @Callback(name = "testCallback",

            operation = @Operation(

                    summary = "Book Callback"

            ),

            ref = "#/components/schemas/CBResp"),

    @Callback(name = "testCallback2",

            operation = @Operation(

                    summary = "Book Callback2"

            ),

            ref = "#/components/schemas/CBResp")})
```

In resulting yml file see:

```
"callbacks": {

      "testCallback": {

        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CBResp"

      }

    }
```

Only 1 callback without many properties.  For me its looking like a heavy bug.
At the same time in documentation i see "detailed" description https://springdoc.org/#are-callbacks-supported

Anyone know how to describe rest calbacks in Java and generate yml?

Thank you.

Comment: Both the annotations look wrong. Callback $refs should point to [Callback Objects](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#callback-object-examples) not to schemas. See the annotation example here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#callback

Comment: @Helen, thank you. Now its working.

Comment: This happened to me when I had an invalid "method" value. I changed it from "POST" to "post" and the yaml is generating now.